# Date comparison in power bi dax

Tags: powerbi, dax

I had a problem with my code. It returns the below error:
DAX comparison operates do not support comparing values of type date with values of type text.

Basically, I want to count rows based on some conditions. And I know there is a need to convert the data type, but I am not sure how to do it.

```
Total Open Issues = 
--------------------
--basic info
VAR SELECTEDDATE =
    DATEVALUE(SELECTEDVALUE(Calender[FullDateAlternateKey].[Date]))
--------------------
--FIND the relvent data
VAR rlvttable =
    calculatetable(
    Tracker,
    Tracker[Catagory]="ISSUE",
    DATEVALUE(Tracker[ClosedDate])>SELECTEDDATE
       ||Tracker[ClosedDate]=""
    )
--------------------
--Results
Return
    countrows(rlvttable)
```

Anyone could advise me how to correct it? Thanks~

Answer (score 1):

Check the data type of columns `Tracker[ClosedDate]` and `Calender[FullDateAlternateKey]` - one of them is `Text`, rather than `Date`.

To fix, you could:

- choose a different field which is already a `Date` format
- change the format of the offending column
- use `DATEVALUE` in your measure, to convert the text date to a real date.

It also looks like you need to edit this statement, as these conditions conflict:

```
Tracker[ClosedDate]>SELECTEDDATE
   &&Tracker[ClosedDate]=""
```

Comment: Thanks, @Olly.  I had done what you had suggested regarding on the date format, still does not work. As for the conditions conflict, I am also struggling how could I correct it. Could you advise? thanks~

Comment: What did you change? I suggested three different methods to fix the problem... With respect to the conflicting conditions - what are you trying to achieve? Your current filter tries to select Closed Dates that are both greater than selected date AND are blank, at the same time...

Comment: I had tried your 3rd method but didnt work. For hte conditions, I am trying to filter both two conditions, i guess i should use OR instead of AND.

Comment: [Edit] your question to show the measure you are now trying. Also, "didn't work" is useless - what exactly happened? An error? An unexpected value? Blank?

Comment: still showing the same msg. DAX comparison operates do not support comparing values of type date with values of type text.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to compare the `closedDate` with `""`. I should use `blank()` instead.